# Is there a way to see created by , last modified by in field definition using tooling api, metadata api or other ways in Apex?

Tags: api, metadata-api

I need to query the Fields highlight in the below snapshot is there any way to query them through tooling API/Rest/SOAP?

Usecase: I need to know who created the custom fields last month.
[image]

Comment: Would need more clarity to your question, like: code snippets trying to make the callout, apex controllers.
As of now, the question is too barren to give answers for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could query [`CustomField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm) object with Tooling API:

```sql
SELECT Id, DeveloperName, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.Name
FROM CustomField
WHERE EntityDefinition.DeveloperName = 'Opportunity' AND DeveloperName = 'ARR'
```

[`FieldDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) has no `CreatedDate` field.

Please note that `DeveloperName` in both `CustomField` and `FieldDefinition` object doesn't include the `__c` suffix, indeed the developerName of your custom field is just `ARR`.

Comment: Agree with @rubenDG

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy values you could use [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customobject.htm) and [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm) objects exposed by Tooling API

For instance this query:

```
Select Id, TableEnumOrId, DeveloperName, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedBy.Name, LastModifiedDate, CreatedDate from CustomField
```

**Will give you:**

> Id - field Id   TableEnumOrId - object Name or Id (if it is custom
> object)
> DeveloperName - field name
> CreatedBy.Name - name of user who created the field
>
> - CreatedBy.Id will give you Id if user who created the field
>
> LastModifiedBy.Name - name of user who last modified the field
> LastModifiedDate - date when field was last modified   CreatedDate -
> date when field was created

The easiest way to obtain this data would probably be via a Tooling API query from Developer Console of (if needs to be automated) via `sfdx cli`.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm

If you have to query the above data from Apex, then you could leverage Apex Tooling API library https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi